# Solving $ y'(t) = -t \cdot { \tan(y) } $ properly

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $ t > 0 $. Solve the differential equation

$$ y'(t) = -t \cdot { \tan(y) } $$

for the initial condition (case 1)

$$ y(0) = { \pi \over 4} $$

and then for (case 2)

$$ y(0) = 0 $$

I somewhat know how to solve this since it's a fairly simple separable equation. My main concerns is that I really don't understand the steps. For example, according to the answer for case 1, once we get

$$ \ln |\sin(y)|= {-t^2 \over 2} + \ln(1/\sqrt{2}) $$

and based on the initial condition, it follows that  $$ 0 \lt y(t) \lt \pi $$

We can thus remove the absolute value delimiters. Why is this the case? I don't immediately see why this follows from the initial condition. And then

$$ y(t) = \arcsin \left({ e^{-t^2/2} \over \sqrt{2}}\right) $$

$$ 0 \lt y(t) \lt {\pi \over 2} $$

This is fairly straightforward I believe, considering the range of the arcsin function.

Comment: @whacka I wasn't clear enough in the description (probably because honestly I didn't understand the problem).

Comment: @user1904218 I don't understand it either, right off the bat it's self-contradictory for $t>0$ and yet the solution is supposed to be defined at $0$.

Comment: There are two initial value problems. Same differential equation, two different initial conditions. Also, the differential equation is supposed to hold for $t>0$. How I know this? I was the one constructing the exam with this problem...

Comment: @mickep I take it OP is asking a question from an ongoing exam that prohibits online help? Just in case that's so, I've deleted my answer. | Edit: okay, thanks, just checking.

Comment: @whacka No, it is an old exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you solve your differential equation, you divide by $\tan y$. This is only allowed if $\tan y\neq 0$. In the first case you start with $y(0)=\pi/4$. Hence, your $y$ must stay between the two zeros $0$ and $\pi$ of $\tan$ (otherwise you have divided by 0 while separating your variables). Since $\sin y>0$ for $0<y<\pi$ you can remove the absolute value. (In fact, you should even have $0<y<\pi/2$, since otherwise $\tan y$ is not defined.)

In the second case, you start with $y(0)=0$. And since $\tan 0=0$, you cannot proceed as in the first case. Could it be that $y(t)=0$ is a solution?

Comment: Thank you, but can't tan(t) be between e.g. pi and 3pi/2 as well?

Comment: Not if you start at $\pi/4$.

Comment: I hate to ask, but could you expand on that?

Comment: Don't worry. It is good if this gets cleared out. If $y(t)$ is continuous and $y(0)=\pi/4$, and $y$ attains the value $5\pi/4$, say. Then it must also attain all values between $\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4$. In particular $y=\pi/2$ and $y=\pi$ for some values of $t$. But at these values $\tan y$ is undefined and zero, respectively. In the case of undefined, the differential equation does not have a meaning, in the case of zero, we are not allowed to divide by $\tan y$. Thus, the only values that are allowed, are $0<y<\pi/2$.

Comment: I totally understand now that you mentioned it being continuous. I found the problem to be a lot harder than it looks, maybe because I tend to oversee simple details like that.